# Sequelizejs "include on" through two fields

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to associate 2 tables with sequelizejs.

Table 1 has a field with an ID that is used for the relationship and table 2 has 2 fields for the relationship, one is module (string) and the ID for the relationship.

**Table1**:
id
order_id
... other fields

**Table2**:
id
module
relation_id
''' other fields

The SQL syntax would be the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 AS t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.order_id = t2.relation_id AND 'SAC' = t2.module
INNER JOIN table3 AS t3 ON t1.c_id = t3.id
WHERE t1.active = 1
```

The sequelize syntax is the following:

```
table1.findAll({
include: [
  { 
    model: sequelize.models.table3
  },
  {
    model: sequelize.models.table2,
    as: 't2',
    on: { 
        'SAC' : {$col: 't2.module'},
        table1.order_id: {$col: 't2.relation_id'}
    }
  }
]
})
.then((result) => {
    ...
})
.catch((err) => {
    ...
});
```

But sequelize gives me the next error:

***Error*** =>  { SequelizeEagerLoadingError: t2 is not associated to table1!

I thank you for your help

Comment: That db design looks wrong. Or its not clear maybe. table1.order_id is the table1 primary key? Sequelize error is clear, you are trying to include a table which is not related to the model.

Comment: Yes but, How to associate with two fields or more.
T2 is associated to several tables through module & relarion_id fields.
Thanks

Comment: forget about table2.module = 'SAC'. Because that's merely a condition you will have in your query. The thing you have to solve is how to tell sequelize that table1 and table2 are associated. Then when you query you add `where: { module: 'SAC' }` in the `include` option and that will work. The association is the problem